# How to bind textFieldShouldClear to a field or another with passing the correct argument?

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 text fields:

```
@IBOutlet weak var countriesFieldVar: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var countriesFieldVar2: UITextField!
```

from my understanding, textFieldShouldClear should execute when we tap the enabled "clear" button that appears at right of the fields.

so I implemented, this:

```
func textFieldShouldClear(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == countriesFieldVar {
        println("field 1")
    } else {
        println("field 2")   
    }
    return true
}
```

This code does nothing, so I guess I should invoque the function and pass it the right text field argument.
but how to invoque the function and pass it the correct argument corresponding to the field where the "clear" is being tapped ?

(I assigned tags to fields). Please answer in swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't invoke the function yourself, it gets called automatically when the clear button is pressed. Did yo uset the delegates on your textFields?

```
countriesFieldVar.delegate = self
countriesFieldVar2.delegate = self
```

Comment: that worked. Thanks a lot. Any reason why I had to put this specifically in viewdidload for it to work ?

Comment: It's how protocol - delegate pattern works, and most of the things in iOS conform to this pattern (textFields, tableViews...). Basically, what you do with that line is say that your class is now listening to the changes for the textField, and that your implementations of certain methods should be fired. You need to set the delegate before you actually start using the textField for them to be called, so the viewDidLoad method is usually the best place.